# Guzzle Bearer Authorization header cannot be setted to request

Tags: symfony, ubuntu-18.04, php-curl, php-7.1, guzzle6

I am trying to set an Authorization header with Guzzle/**6.2.0** on Ubuntu **18.04.1**. But I cannot set it. Can anyone help me with this problem?

**I have following code:**

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
$url = 'my_url';
$client = new Client();
$response = $client->get( $url, [
      'headers' => [ 
              'Authorization' => "Bearer {$my_token}" 
   ]
]);

echo '<pre>';
print_r(json_decode($response->getBody(), true));
echo '</pre>';
```

*The server returns all the headers from the request. Here in this function, the authorization header is no longer present.*

```
return $this->handleView($this->view([
    'headers' => $request->headers->all()
], 200));
```

**And answer is:**

```
Array {
    [headers] => Array {
         [host] => Array{ [0]=>'my_url' }
         [user-agent] => Array { [0] => GuzzleHttp/6.2.0 curl/7.58.0 PHP/7.1.22-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 }
         [x-php-ob-level] => Array{ [0] => 1 }
    }
}
```

So, "Authorization" was not setted.

Thank you!

Comment: Show us the code that generates this “answer” as well, otherwise we have no way of knowing whether you are drawing the correct conclusion or not.

Comment: The header is set on the http `request` that you send to a server. The server will check the authentification header to authorize you (or not) to do what you want. After execute the action/code behind `$url` it return you a response, that you call `answer`. You are dumping the response and not the request

Comment: I edited my question and added the server code. Also, this currently works on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: What is the error when isn't `working`?

Comment: The problem is that, i set the Authorization on header and i expect to receive back this field with authorization, but it's missing... The authorization field contained my_token, so, i need it further.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: yes. 
https://support.deskpro.com/en/kb/articles/missing-authorization-headers-with-apache

Comment: https://devhacksandgoodies.wordpress.com/2014/06/27/apache-pass-authorization-header-to-phps-_serverhttp_authorization/

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with the [`debug`](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#debug) option turned on? What do you see in the logs?

Also can you upgrade to the latest version? I don't remember any bugs related to the question, but if you want to report it in the end, you have to do it against the latest version.